# Ubuntu 17.10 final beta

Tags: upgrade, beta, 17.10

my question is about the new upcoming Ubuntu release, i.e. 17.10 gnome. If I install already the final beta version on my machine, will it be upgraded, over the time, to 17.10 release on 19th of October (when it's been Scheduled) or I should wait the release?
The other question would be, how stable is the final beta? Have somebody already tested it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMO you should not run pre-release (alpha / beta) unless you are willing to accept some bugs and report any problem you find on launchapd, ie file a bug report. Personally, unless there is some feature I need, I wait a month after release . This gives some time for most major bugs to be resolved and less stress on servers as everyone is downloading on release day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,, if you load and run the beta, and install upgrades as they become  available it will become the release version.

As to stability, it *is* a beta version.  Alpha versions have been run for some time (I run one in a VM) and I have experienced few problems, but this is only an opinion.